# Does a creature killed by a Shadow Dragon's Shadow Breath become undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, dragons

Regarding [Shadow Dragons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-d#ShadowDragonTemplate), the *Monster Manual* (p. 85) states:

> Any damage-dealing breath weapon possessed by the dragon deals
>   necrotic damage instead of its original damage type. A humanoid
>   reduced to 0 hit points by this damage dies, and an undead shadow
>   rises from its corpse and acts immediately after the dragon in the
>   initiative count. The shadow is under the dragon's control.

Does this necessarily mean that the humanoid becomes the undead shadow? It should clearly state that, if that is the case. This matters in case the party wishes to raise the character from the dead via a *revivify* or *raise dead* spell.

Comment: I found the answer myself after further searching. I decided to answer my own question instead of deleting.

Comment: Thank you! That’s the preferred way to handle that situation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### The undead shadow is literally the humanoid's actual shadow, turned into an undead monster. It is not the humanoid's soul itself.

The *Monster Manual* entry for the [Shadow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-s#Shadow) states:

> If a creature from which a shadow has been created somehow returns to
>   life, its undead shadow senses the return. The shadow might seek its
>   "parent" to vex or slay. Whether the shadow pursues its living
>   counterpart, the creature that birthed the shadow no longer casts one
>   until the monster is destroyed.

Comment: Does it give advantage to stealth-checks or anything if one doesn't have a shadow?

Comment: @Deduplicator I'd ask that as its own question.

Comment: This paints Peter Pan in a more grim light...

Answer (score 0):

**No, the humanoid is just dead.**

The shadow rises from the corpse. The corpse doesn't become a shadow, it just appears out of it.

Comment: Even when correct, an answer is always better when it includes support for its conclusion.